# vetorizar média móvel de uma matriz no R

Tags: r, matriz

Estou fazendo a seguinte operação com uma matriz no R:

```
> m <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3, nrow = 3)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> m2 <- m
> for(i in 1:nrow(m)){
+   for(j in 1:ncol(m)){
+     c <- expand.grid((i-1):(i+1), (j-1):(j+1))
+     c <- c[c[,1] > 0 & c[,2]>0 & c[,1] <= nrow(m) & c[,2] <= ncol(m),]
+     m2[i,j] <- mean(m[c[,1], c[,2]])
+   }
+ }
> m2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  3.0  4.5  6.0
[2,]  3.5  5.0  6.5
[3,]  4.0  5.5  7.0
```

Ou seja, estou calculando para cada elemento da matriz a média de seus elementos adjacentes.

No entanto, minhas matrizes são imagens e este método passa a ser muito ineficiente para matrizes grandes...

Alguém sabe se existe alguma forma de vetorizar este loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem pacotes com este tipo de função. Adaptando a [resposta postada no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553069/spatial-data-compute-metrics-on-neighbors-in-r/22554904#22554904):

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(m)
as.matrix(focal(r, matrix(1,3,3), mean, pad = TRUE, padValue = NA, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Resultando em:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  3.0  4.5  6.0
[2,]  3.5  5.0  6.5
[3,]  4.0  5.5  7.0
```

Podemos comparar a performance utilizando uma matriz um pouco maior:

```
mbig <- matrix(1:441, ncol = 21, nrow = 21)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(Daniel = {
  m2 <- mbig
  for(i in 1:nrow(mbig)){
     for(j in 1:ncol(mbig)){
       c <- expand.grid((i-1):(i+1), (j-1):(j+1))
       c <- c[c[,1] > 0 & c[,2]>0 & c[,1] <= nrow(mbig) & c[,2] <= ncol(mbig),]
       m2[i,j] <- mean(mbig[c[,1], c[,2]])
     }
   }
  },
  Raster = {
    r <- raster(mbig)
    as.matrix(focal(r, matrix(1,nrow(mbig),ncol(mbig)), mean, pad = TRUE, padValue = NA, na.rm = TRUE))
})
```

A diferença parece ser significativa:

```
 Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval cld
 Daniel 116.16301 118.47165 121.1388 119.32912 120.54214 204.8606   100   b
 Raster  13.16006  13.41737  14.0498  13.61459  13.87249  31.2184   100  a
```